# upload csv with logstash to elasticsearch with new mappings

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have a csv file which I'm tryng to upload to ES using Logstash. My conf file is as follows:

```
input {
  file {
    path => ["filename"]
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}

filter {
  csv {
    columns => ["name1", "name2", "name3", ...]
    separator => ","
  }
}

filter {
  mutate {
    remove_field => ["name31", "name32", "name33"]
  }
}

output {
  stdout{
    codec => rubydebug
}

elasticsearch {
  action => "index"
  host => "localhost"
  index => "newindex"
  template_overwrite => true
  document_type => "newdoc"
  template => "template.json"
  }
}
```

My template file looks like the following:

```
{
"mappings": {
    "newdoc": {
        "properties": {
            "name1": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "name2": {
                "type": "float"
            },
            "name3": {
                "format": "dateOptionalTime",
                "type": "date"
            },
            "name4": {
                "index": "not_analyzed",
                "type": "string"
            },
            ....
        }
     }
 },
  "settings": {
    "number_of_replicas": 0,
    "number_of_shards": 1
 },
 "template": "newindex"
 }
```

When I try to overwrite the default mapping, I get an 400 error even when I only try to write one line:

```
failed action with response of 400, dropping action: ["index", + ...
```

What can be the problem? Everything works fine if I don't overwrite the mapping but that is not a solution for me. I'm using Logstash 1.5.1 and Elasticsearch 1.5.0 on Red Hat.

Thanks

Comment: You get an error when replacing the mapping, or when indexing a document?  Perhaps the full error message might provide more info.  Elasticsearch will drop messages that are incompatible with the mapping...

Comment: @Alain Your comment got me thinking and after looking carefully, one of my date fields was not formatted properly. I modified the ES date format and everything is running as it is suppose to.

Answer (score 0):

You should POST your request 'mapping' to elasticsearch before loading data in elasticsearch

[POST mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/indices-put-mapping.html)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create the index before running logstash , It does create the index if you haven't yet , but it's better to create your own mapping before runing your conf file with logstash . Gives you more control over your field types etc.. Here is a simple tutorial on how to import csv to elasticsearch using logstash : http://freefilesdl.com/how-to-connect-logstash-to-elasticsearch-output